# Xcode Swift pods installation - import file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on a project in Xcode written in Swift. I'm using two pods, `AFNetworking` and `BDBOAuth1Manager`. They're both Obj-C libraries, so a simple bridging file to import them takes care of everything.

Now, the problem arrises when I try to include a third pod, `SwiftyJSON`, that's written in Swift. Here's what the Podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

pod "AFNetworking"
pod "BDBOAuth1Manager"
pod "SwiftyJSON"

link_with 'TwitterSearch', 'TwitterSearch Tests'
```

After installing the above Podfile, the bridging header stops working, because it now it can't find the files I'm trying to import.

To clarifty, this is the bridging header file:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"
```

It works when the Pods are just `AFNetworking` and `BDBOAuth1Manager`, which are written in Obj-C. It doesn't work when a third pod, `SwiftyJSON`, written in Swift, is included.

The exact error messages are:

- Swift compiler error: "BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h" file not
  found
- Swift compiler error: Failed to import bridging header
  path-to-bridging-header

Any idea what this might be?

**UPDATE:** I've figured out why it wasn't working. When I manually added in SwiftyJSON, everything worked fine. The entire problem roots back to this line: `use_frameworks!`
I'm not at all familiar with frameworks, but practically speaking you'd have to do the following:

```
#import "path/BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"

instead of

#import "BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"
```

Comment: Path is the path of the imported file, respective to the importing file, if that makes any sense. And sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

## Workaround

**Podfile**:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'SwiftAndObjCPods' do
pod "SwiftyJSON"
end

target 'SwiftAndObjCPodsTests' do
pod "SwiftyJSON"
end
```

**Project:**

Drag & drop the current versions of `AFNetworking` and `BDBOAuth1Manager` directly into your project. You can do so by locating these in the **Pods** group > Pods > Show in Finder, and simply move these to a convenient tmporary location.

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"
```

**Swift usage**

```
// No import
let a = BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager(baseURL: baseURL, consumerKey: "consumer", consumerSecret: "secret")
```

*Tested: links, builds, runs.*

Answer (score 1):

## No Workaround

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'ObjCSwiftPods' do
pod "AFNetworking"
pod "BDBOAuth1Manager"
pod "SwiftyJSON"
end

target 'ObjCSwiftPodsTests' do
pod "AFNetworking"
pod "BDBOAuth1Manager"
pod "SwiftyJSON"
end
```

**-Bridging-Header**

```
#import "../Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h"
#import "../Pods/BDBOAuth1Manager/BDBOAuth1Manager/BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h"
```

Note about Bridging-Header:

*Replacing `../` by `{full path to Pods}/` inexplicably got me there when Xcode acted-up.*

**Swift invocation**

```
// necessary import
import SwiftyJSON

// test BDBOAuth1Manager
let url = NSURL(string: "http://ObjCSwiftPods.com")
let bdsm = BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager(baseURL: url, consumerKey:"key", consumerSecret:"secret")

// test AFNetworking
let sec = AFSecurityPolicy()

// test SwiftyJSON
let json = JSON("{}")
```

---

Answer (score 0):

try adding version to the podfile like so

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
```

Comment: what are your cocoapods version and deploy target?

Comment: Cocoapods version is 0.38.2. Not sure what you mean by deploy target.

Comment: Deploy target is the minimal iOS version your app is targeting to.

Comment: Oh. That would be 8.0.

Comment: Well, then It seems like it is something with cocoa pods, because SwiftyJSON's minimal conditions are met. Hot-fix would be to add .swift files manually into the project.