# If using Cocoapods and use_frameworks!, should I use Obj-C Bridging Header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

[This link](http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html) says no.

But that example only deals with Swift classes. In my project, which uses `use_frameworks!` I've got a swift class that uses an objective-c **class**. Both of those classes are in the same directory in my local development pod. Without a bridging header, how can the swift class make use of the objective-c class?

To clarify:
The question isn't about whether Swift can import frameworks. I know it can. The question is twofold:

- Should I use a bridging header if I'm using `use_frameworks!`? Or, will using a bridging header cause unexpected issues, as indicated in the post I linked to above?
- If I can't use a bridging header, then I need to import an objective-c *class* (not framework) from a swift class, and both of those classes are in the same framework. I don't know how that could even be possible without a bridging header.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: I have a similar setup, but I have an objective-c framework in the swift pod. Does it work with the bridging header?

Comment: The downvote, albeit not mine, may be related to the *Primary Opinion Based* aspect of this question. You are asking **should** instead of **must**, which is open to interpretation. My interpretation, as a matter of fact, is that you *should*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

It has nothing to do with `use_frameworks!`, it has to do with exposing your `Obj-C` pods to **Swift**.

See examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742131/218152
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31777069/218152

Comment: Thanks. These are great, but using Cocoapods shouldn't require us to directly modify properties in an Xcode project. One of the main purposes of Cocoapods is for it to take care of linkages and dependencies without us having to directly modify Xcode settings.

Comment: I guess that `pod install` could technically add the missing bridging headers, and insert `#import` for the `Obj-C` source code, or some other method that would hide this step entirely. I'm just grateful that Cocoapods have so nicely adapted to **Swift** in the first place.